# sqlalchemy group_by and count

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask as a python framework with sqlalchemy. The models use the query_property which helps me build queries:

```
class Person(object):
        query = db_session.query_property()
        ....

persons = Person.query.all()
```

Each person has a city, state and country where he lives in and I want to gather all results and output something like:

```
    Country     State       City        Persons(count)
================================================================================
    US      NY      New York    10
    DE      Berlin      Berlin      100
```

This obviously needs a select count and group by country, state, city. The group by thing works but I dont know how to implement the counting since query property has no select method in which case I would write:

```
Person.query.select([Person.country, Person.state, Person.city, func.count(Person.id)]).all()
```

Anyone with an idea how to use [query_property](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html?highlight=query_property#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.ScopedSession.query_property) with group_by and count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - you cannot do it using `query_property` because it implicitely selects the whole object (all attributes of it), so adding the `group_by` would not produce the desired result because undesired columns are included in the non-aggregate part of the query.

However you can simply use a `db_session.query([Person.country, ...]).group_by(...)`. So all you need to do is to add `db_session` property to the `Person` class along with `query` and then use it to create a desired query explicitely:

```
class Person(object):
    session = db_session
    query = db_session.query_property()
    ....
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`add_columns`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.add_columns) method on `Person.query` to append computed values:

```
Person.query.add_columns(func.count(...)).group_by(...).all()
```

Keep in mind that you get back a list of tuples (not Person objects). However, each tuple contains the Person object and the computed value:

```
[(<Person object>, 3), (<Person object>, 7), ...]
```